# FullCalendar: Add background-color for the whole day not for the event alone through 'addEventSource'

Tags: css, json, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I want to add background color for the whole day and not the event background alone. For the code that i have written now, i could see events alone as background
  My view code is as follows:

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>/cmn/calendar/show_holidays",
    type: 'POST', // Send post data
    data: 'type=fetch',
    async: true,

    success: function(s){
          holidays = s;
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', JSON.parse(holidays));
           }
             });

    /* initialize the calendar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        utc: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, 

    });
    });
```

And My codeigniter controller code is as follows:

```
    public function show_holidays()
    {
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $holidays=$this->calendar_m->show_holidays();
    foreach($holidays as &$val){
     $val['allDay'] = 'true'; 
     $val['Rendering'] = 'Background'; 
     $val['textColor'] = '#000';
     $val['title'] = 'Holiday today' 
     $val['backgroundColor'] = 'yellow'; // added background color to all the holidays
            }
     echo json_encode($holidays);
}
```

So i am passing the data through json. I get the output as follows:-
[image]

Now i want the yellow color event to be look like the background color in sundays.(i.e.) background color for the whole day not for the event alone.
Is it possible through 'addEventSource'? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. You just have a tiny case sensitive mistake

```
$val['Rendering'] = 'Background';
```

change it to

```
$val['rendering'] = 'background';
```

Both the 'R' and 'B' to 'r' and 'b'

Comment: ok now i got the full background color but the events' name are missing.. what should i do?

Comment: There is not enough details on your code to tell, try to set the textColor: '#000' (white), and make sure your events have the "title" property (this is the event's name). Let me know if it did the job

Comment: I have added the "title" and i made the textcolor as '#000'. But i didnt get the events. The thing is i comment the  '//$val['Rendering'] = 'Background'; ' , then i get the events ..?

Comment: Did you tried to change the color to more contrasted one? Because actually white text on yellow background is not so visible

Comment: $val['color'] = 'black'; $val['textColor'] = 'white'; I tried like this also.. I didnot get the event

Comment: Can you post the exact holiday json you render?

Comment: $.ajax({
 url: "show_holidays",
        type: 'POST', // Send post data
        data: 'type=fetch',
        async: true,
        success: function(s){
                 holidays = s;              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', JSON.parse(holidays));
                   }
 }); ->controller code is :-public function show_holidays()
    {   foreach($holidays as &$val){
         $val['allDay'] = 'true'; 
         $val['title'] = 'hiwq';
         $val['rendering'] = 'background';  
         $val['title'] = 'ound'; 
 }
         echo json_encode($holidays);
    }

Comment: I meant the json result. What you have in the "holidays" variable after the ajax call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112650/discussion-between-keynes-and-eyal-abir).

Comment: This fiddle works fine for single $.ajax https://jsfiddle.net/xxrznf2j/, but when i am making two $.ajax what should i do?

Comment: What do you mean by 2 ajax?

Comment: I have added my code along withmy previous discussion

Comment: Sorry I can't understand where is the code you are talking about. Please refer by link

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112650/discussion-between-keynes-and-eyal-abir

Answer (score 0):

The following is the fiddle that displays the output. I got the background color for the whole day and not the event background alone. It is achieved through 'addEventSource' 
Hope this Helps..!

```
var jsonEvents = 
[{allDay 
: 
"true" ,
backgroundColor 
: 
"red" ,
id 
: 
13 ,
rendering 
: 
"background" ,
start 
: 
"2016-05-01" ,
textColor 
: 
"white" ,
title 
: 
"Mayday",
className
:
"event-full"
}]


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 

utc: true, 
header: { 
left: 'prev,next today', 
center: 'title', 
right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' 
}, 
editable: true, 
droppable: true, 

eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) { 
element.append(event.title); 
} 

});


$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', jsonEvents);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xxrznf2j/[image: This image shows the event is in full background color]